# Error installing eclipse che using chectl - FailedScheduling

Tags: qemu, minikube, kvm, eclipse-che

I've been trying to install Eclipse Che with minikube for a while and there is a point where I can't get ahead.

That point is right after you run the

```
chectl server:start --platform minikube
```

And the error comes at this point:

```
 ❯ ✅  Post installation checklist
    ❯ PostgreSQL pod bootstrap
      ✔ scheduling...done.
      ✖ downloading images
        → ERR_TIMEOUT: Timeout set to pod wait timeout 300000
```

...

```
    Show important messages
 ›   Error: Error: ERR_TIMEOUT: Timeout set to pod wait timeout 300000
 ›   Installation failed, check logs in '/tmp/chectl-logs/1592460423915'
```

If we look at the output of the log we see a fault that repeats

```
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
```

This would be the complete output of the log

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON              OBJECT                    MESSAGE
0s          Normal   ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/che-operator   Scaled up replica set che-operator-7f7575f6fb to 1
0s          Normal   SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/che-operator-7f7575f6fb   Created pod: che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9
0s          Normal   Scheduled           pod/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9    Successfully assigned che/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9 to minikube
0s          Normal   Pulling             pod/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9    Pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-operator:7.14.2"
0s          Normal   Pulled              pod/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9    Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-operator:7.14.2"
0s          Normal   Created             pod/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9    Created container che-operator
0s          Normal   Started             pod/che-operator-7f7575f6fb-xjqg9    Started container che-operator
0s          Normal   SuccessfulCreate    job/che-tls-job                      Created pod: che-tls-job-6pj8p
0s          Normal   Scheduled           pod/che-tls-job-6pj8p                Successfully assigned che/che-tls-job-6pj8p to minikube
0s          Normal   Pulling             pod/che-tls-job-6pj8p                Pulling image "quay.io/eclipse/che-tls-secret-creator:alpine-3029769"
0s          Normal   Pulled              pod/che-tls-job-6pj8p                Successfully pulled image "quay.io/eclipse/che-tls-secret-creator:alpine-3029769"
0s          Normal   Created             pod/che-tls-job-6pj8p                Created container che-tls-job-job-container
0s          Normal   Started             pod/che-tls-job-6pj8p                Started container che-tls-job-job-container
0s          Normal   Completed           job/che-tls-job                      Job completed
0s          Normal   ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal   ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal   ScalingReplicaSet      deployment/postgres                   Scaled up replica set postgres-59b797464c to 1
0s          Normal   SuccessfulCreate       replicaset/postgres-59b797464c        Created pod: postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Warning   FailedScheduling       pod/postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl         running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "postgres-59b797464c-vdfnl": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
0s          Normal    ExternalProvisioning   persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-data   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" or manually created by system administrator
```

At this point I don't know how to proceed. I currently have a minikube installed with kvm2. The machine that runs it is a virtual machine with nested virtualization enabled. 
Following the advice of the documentation of de che lanzo minikube with at least 4GB of ram(the virtual machine has at least 6). I also came to try a solution I found here in stack to the timeout error, it was simply to extend the waiting time, so the error took longer to appear and I finally realized what a rookie I was and I got to look at the log.

This is the list of versions I have installed

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

minikube version: v1.11.0
commit: 57e2f55f47effe9ce396cea42a1e0eb4f611ebbd

Client Version: 
   version.Info{
                Major:"1", 
                Minor:"18", 
                GitVersion:"v1.18.3", 
                GitCommit:"2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40", 
                GitTreeState:"clean", 
                BuildDate:"2020-05-20T12:52:00Z", 
                GoVersion:"go1.13.9", 
                Compiler:"gc", 
                Platform:"linux/amd64"
               }

Eclipse Che CLI

VERSION
  chectl/7.14.2 linux-x64 node-v10.21.0

QEMU emulator version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-8+deb10u5)
Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with minikube 1.7.3 version instead of minikube 1.11.0.
I faced the same issue and its resolved with 1.7.3 version.

I hope it will helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: With which version of kubectl? I read that the version of kubectl should be close to the client version, for example, if I understand correctly, if I install minikube 1.7.3. The version of kubectl should be at least 1.6... correct? or do you for example use the most recent one?

Comment: EDIT: I've already seen the facility download its own kubectl.

Well, thanks a lot!!!, I have finally installed che using the version you indicated and it seems to work!!